# Coordinates within Model/Mesh

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
is there any possibility to check whether certain coordinates are within a given model or not? Can I somehow build up an occupancy grid of model ?
Any help would be great?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1754/coordinates-within-model/mesh/) by [Max Stähr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/224/max-st%C3%A4hr/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The closest thing you can do is probably by using ray casting.

This [section of the tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/custom_messages#Collision_Map_Creator_Plugin) does something similar to create a collision map.

You can also use the `World::GetEntityBelowPoint()` function

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1